# Log in one user at a time - Working with XAMPP MySQL and VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin, xampp

We're task to create a VB.NET program with a XAMPP-MySQL database that will be networked for several computers using LAN for our project. It will be a role-based system. Each user will show a different dashboard after log in based on what role they have in the organization. For example the type of these accounts are billing, admin, and sales personnel each have their account. Only one user per account type.

Is it possible with XAMPP and VB.NET to only limit one account type to log in in one computer (e.g. if billing is already logged in in computer1, they can't log in billing in computer2 anymore. they can log in in computer2 if billing logged out of computer1)? If it is, how can we achieve this?

**Example:**

- **Computer 1** - Billing is logged in
- **Computer 2** - Admin in logged in
- **Computer 3** - Billing is trying to log in again but it will fail because it is already logged in on Computer 1

Comment: "one user per account [role] type" misses the whole point of role-based security.

Comment: Oh, and **of course** it's possible to limit logins, but you have to design the storage and code to make it happen. It's not automatic.